# Created a Database and Join Code won't return results

Tags: sql

I created a database and I am trying to run code for a JOIN. I don't receive any errors, but it also doesn't return any results. Below is the code I have come up with including the rows I have inserted into the tables.

```
INSERT INTO USERS(EmailAddress, FirstName, LastName)
VALUES
    ('johnsmith@gmai[enter image description here][1]l.com', 'John', 'Smith'),
    ('janedoe@yahoo.com', 'Jane', 'Doe')

INSERT INTO Downloads(FileName, DownloadDate)
VALUES
    ('pedals_are_falling.mp3', GETDATE()),
    ('turn_signal.mp3', GETDATE()),
    ('one_horse_town.mp3', GETDATE())

INSERT INTO Product(ProductName)
VALUES
    ('Local Music Vol 1'),
    ('Local Music Vol 2')

SELECT EmailAddress AS email_address, 
       FirstName AS first_name,
       LastName AS last_name,
       DownloadDate AS download_date, 
       FileName, 
       ProductName AS product_name
FROM Downloads JOIN Users
ON Downloads.UserID = Users.UserID
JOIN Product 
ON Product.ProductID = Downloads.ProductID
ORDER BY EmailAddress;
```

Comment: If you want to JOIN downloads on userID/productID than you need these fields in this table (your inserts do not include them). In this case I assume that it is one-to-one relationship as this is what it looks like based on your SELECT. If you need many-to-many (which is most likely based on names of tables) than you need intermediary tables like UsersDownloads where you put userID and downloadID and only then join through them.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: There are no `UserID` columns in your inserts.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you don't get errors, I assume that the join columns referenced in the query do exist.  But you are not giving them values in your INSERT statements.

So you should look at the actual data in the tables, which I imagine should make very clear why the join is not finding matching rows.

Either you have no values in those columns, or you are auto-generating values on each insert.  Either way, you have nothing in your inserts to indicate which downloads go with which user, or which products go with which downloads.